# running htdocts and clusterd tomcat webapp on same Apache

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7, cluster-computing

I have created tomcat cluster using apache and mod_jk module. load balancing working fine and i can access the webapp directory's projects. but the problem is after i configured the cluster, now i cannot access the htdocs projects.
any solutions please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure virtual host settings(/apache/conf/httpd.conf) with no-jk to access Apache webapp.

```
    <VirtualHost *:80> 
   ................................   
   ................................

    SetEnvIf Request_URI "/url$" no-jk 

   </VirtualHost>
```